# Can't log to oracle local DB using PHP with WebMatrix- shows an empty page

Tags: php, oracle, connection, webmatrix

I've been trying to use the following code to connect to the oracle db from WebMatrix:

```
<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("sys","password","//localhost:1521/xe");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

For some reason, it just shows an empty page in the browser (Chrome). 
Any other thing I'm trying to program using php (like echo hello world and such) are working. 
What's weird that I don't even see a message of failure or success. 
I'm using windows 7 64bit.

Got any idea what might be the problem ? (I've searched all over and tried many things before asking here).

Comment: Ok, I believe I've got the problem. I'll share it with others who would have the same question in the future. Since it's a server-side language (PHP), you won't be able to view it on your browser unless you reach it from inside a server (Apache is quite common for usage as a server). Right now I'm going to Install it and see how it works. Hope this answer will lead people with the same problem to look into Apache :)

Comment: Ok. I've found on youtube 2 videos that helped me a lot. Just take a look and be patient. It's worth it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17qhikHv5hY      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y6lOHov3Bk